# Bootstrap 3 - 4 inline inputs in modal with same spaces

Tags: html, css, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have modal window and i want 4 inline inputs. But they have 15px padding on side and beetween 2 inputs is total 30px padding.

How is possible make 15px space beetween inputs?

edit: I want same spacing on sides and beetween inputs.

My try on jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/321/)

Code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of overriding the default css for col-* i would add a custom class then add css to that class to adjusst as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option. You can add a class and a bit of css:

```
.spacing > div + div{padding-left: 0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5u2paavk/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use a special class to adjust the padding and negative margins on the `row` and `col-` like this:

```
.row.no-margin {
    margin-left: -7.5px;
    margin-right: -7.5px;
}

.row.no-margin > .col-xs-3{
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
}
```

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/6C4WCDnnQC)

Comment: thx. i was updated question - my goal is the same spacing on sides and beetween inputs. Your solution makes spacing beetween inputs to 15px but on sides is 7.5px..

Comment: Ok, then you can just remove the .row margin with a special class.. I updated the answer

Comment: So then how does the accepted answer resolve this outer column padding issue?

Comment: Yes. But i am looking on your answer too. Looks like both are correct.